# Result of arithmetic evaluation in buffer, not echo area

Tags: insert, eval-expression

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1

I want to do some arithmetic operation I do this:
[image]

The result is in the echo area, but I want the result to be in cursor place in the buffer.  Something like this:

[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: Is that supposed to be a "won't"? If yes, Emacs may be the wrong editor for you...

Comment: Emacs is not wrong editor fo me. I use it many years. Sorry for my English. It's not my native language.

Comment: I have a function in my emacs config that I think I got from the bottom of [this post](https://emacs.wordpress.com/2007/01/17/eval-and-replace-anywhere/).

Comment: If you are in the `*scratch*` buffer, `C-j` will evaluate the expression before the cursor and place the value of the expression in the buffer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Short version: yes

Instead of `C-x C-e` to evaluate the expression, give it a prefix
argument.  `C-u C-x C-e` will print the output to the buffer.

#### How I found this information

You can investigate how Emacs does these things by looking in
the
[manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html),
or asking Emacs itself.

To see what a particular keybinding does, you can use `C-h k`
(`describe-key`).  You were evaluating the expression with `C-x
C-e`, and you can figure out what that keybinding calls with `C-h
k C-x C-e`.  That will display the command's docstring, the first
part of which is:

> `C-x C-e` runs the command `eval-last-sexp` (found in global-map),
>   which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `elisp-mode.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-x C-e`.
>
> `(eval-last-sexp EVAL-LAST-SEXP-ARG-INTERNAL)`
>
> Evaluate sexp before point; print value in the echo area.
>   **Interactively, with a non `-` prefix argument, print output into
>   current buffer.**
>
> ...

I highlighted the key phrase: giving it a prefix argument (`C-u`)
will print the output to the buffer, rather than the echo area.

Comment: It's good, but it not enough. If I use command `C-u C-x C-e` the result will be **(* 60 3)180**. But I need only **180** (as in my screenshot).

Comment: @user8542613 : then you will need to write your own command.

Comment: @user8542613 : I think Drew's answer does exactly what you want. Please consider switching accepted answers.

Answer (score 9):

Bind this to some key.

```el
(defun foo ()
  "Replace sexp before point by result of its evaluation."
  (interactive)
  (let ((result  (pp-to-string (eval (pp-last-sexp) lexical-binding))))
    (delete-region (save-excursion (backward-sexp) (point)) (point))
    (insert result)))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do an arithmetic operation and insert the value into the buffer, but don't care where you do the operation, then you can also do `C-u M-:` and type the operation info the minibuffer.

This [blog](http://irreal.org/blog/?p=297) has

```
(defun eval-and-replace (value)
  "Evaluate the sexp at point and replace it with its value"
  (interactive (list (eval-last-sexp nil)))
  (kill-sexp -1)
  (insert (format "%S" value)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to do (also complex) computations in Emacs' calc `C-x * *` and then copy its result in the buffer where my cursor was with `y`, `q` closes the calc buffers and I'm back at this location.

Comment: This is what I use all the time.  Also, if you want an algebraic expression, you can do C-x * q, enter an expression, then the answer will be on the kill ring, so you can insert it into the buffer with C-y.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same wish and hadn't used Emacs in a long while and forgot how to do it :)  Very simple and touched on by some above answers with the prefix command `C-u`

Simply `C-u M-:` (Eval buffer appears for your function) such as
`Eval: (- 5 2)` and the result of `3` will appear in your buffer cursor location

This is very handy for kbd-macros where you need to manipulate some arithmetic and replace values

Comment: If you're in `Lisp interaction` buffer mode, like `*scratch*`, `C-j` with pos after last expression parenthesis will evaluate it. Note that such evaluation is postion dependent, so place point where the expression is complete.