# Fewer keystrokes for calculating in org mode

Tags: org-mode, calc, text

When I need while editing a `.org` file to calculate, say, `23.45 * 15`, I copy (<kbd>M-w</kbd>) that string then call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `calc`.

I paste the numbers as a string, preceded by a single tick (using algebraic mode so I don't have to reenter the numbers or the operation).

Once the answer comes back (`351.75`), I mark+copy the output, return (two instances of <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>) and paste (<kbd>C-y</kbd>) the result.

It almost works. I get `1:  351.75` rather than `351.75`, but I'm sure there is a superior way that doesn't involve quite so many keystrokes. Can you suggest one?

###### P.S.1

I am familiar with the basic
[spreadsheet](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-Spreadsheet.html)
in `org-mode`, but here I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing for much simpler needs.

###### P.S.2

The same problem arises with `.txt` file, but a solution using what's available in `.org` is quite adequate.

#### Related

- [Quickly Evaluate Infix Math Expression?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/38425/28733)
- [Evaluate algebraic formula in the buffer in place](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/54265/28733)
- [Result of arithmetic evaluation in buffer, not echo area](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/35392/28733)

Comment: One way is the make the expression you want to calculate into a `calc` src block and evaluate it. Mark the expression, do `C-c C-, s` to add the src block delimiters, type `calc` to make it into a `calc` src block and `C-c C-c` to evaluate it. You still have to do a bunch of keystrokes for that and then another bunch to clean things up though, so I'm not sure whether you are saving anything. You also have to enable `calc` as an Org babel language in your init file (it's not enabled by default), but that's a one-time thing. And you might define a keyboard macro/function to do the setup/cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one–off calculations, use `C-u M-x quick-calc`. It prompts for an algebraic expression and then inserts the result into the buffer at point.

Answer (score 2):

```
(use-package macro-math
  :bind ("\C-x=" . macro-math-eval-region)
        ("\C-x~" . macro-math-eval-and-round-region))
```

This works in any Emacs buffer - Org, text, email, etc. You can modify it to replace the equation rather than append `= <ans>` if you prefer.

http://nschum.de/src/emacs/macro-math/

Answer (score 0):

You already have perhaps `org-babel-do-load-languages` for, say, `python`. Insert a line for calc.

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((python . t)
   (calc . t)))
```

Now write

```
#+begin_src calc
23.45 * 15
#+end_src
```

and type <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> on the expression. A solution block will be inserted.

```
#+begin_src calc
23.45 * 15
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 351.75
```

If you prefer, `org-mode` can generate the block for you if you mark `23.45 * 15`, and type <kbd>C-c C-, s</kbd>, followed by  `calc`.

*Credit for this answer: NickD*